# How to run electron-packager offline without internet?

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I have an Angular project. I want to convert him to Desktop application. For this i use Electron.js.

I can run

```
electron .
```

It works fine.

But now i want to make an exe.
For this i want to use electron-packager.

The problem:
I run:

```
electron-packager . --platform=win32
```

The error:
`getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN github.com`

I understand that electron-packager needs github, but how to solve it?! Again i work offline(with jfrog artifactory) without internet.

Is there another electron package which can do the same without internet? (make an exe)

Comment: Although I can't currently check whether it's possible via the CLI, you could try to fiddle with some options. In the JavaScript API, there's [`electronZipDir`](https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/main/interfaces/electronpackager.options.html#electronzipdir) which allows you to specify the directory into which you have downloaded the Electron ZIP file. However, that means that you'll need some sort of internet connection. Completely offline won't work, AFAIK, because the NPM module `electron` does not provide the correct version of the required executable files.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander Leithner ! It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that electron-packager go to github.com to download electron.js.

So as @Alexander Leithner said to use electronZipDir option. (and also malept in electron channel in Discord)

The solution is simple, when you executed:

```
npm install electron
```

A zip file of the binaries of electron are cached in your computer.

The command for electron-packager looks like this:

```
npm install  -D electron-packager
npx electron-packager  .  -- platform=win32 --electronZipDir=C:/Users/baruc/AppData/Local/electron/Cache/**some long string**
```

Thats all

Edit 25/7/2021
Theoretically, electron-packager has an option called "download" which you can pass to him a "cacheRoot" or "mirrorOptions" to download the electron.zip file.
By default you dont need to change the cacheRoot, but unfortunately both options of the download didnt work for me.

BTW, mirrorOptions got an object, not a string. So its not clear how to pass an object from the command line.

I saw that in the file artifact-utils.js of the @electron/get library, and there in the function called "mirrorVar" it search a special environment variables or the mirrorOptions which i tell before. If this function wont find them it will take the default which is github.

Solution when you have an artifactory:

1. Create in your project an .npmrc file and write there:
   ELECTRON_MIRROR="http://my mirror site/electron/"
   Be aware that it end with back slash.
2. Go to package.json file, and there to scripts write:
   "pac": "electron-packager -- . --platform=win32"

3.execute it: npm run pac